# Use camera in another third party application in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I'm developing an application in which I want to use the camera in my application.  Is there any API by which I can control the camera in blackberry?

Comment: Download the project from this link https://github.com/amrishodiq/Blackberry-Development-Tutorial/tree/master/TakingPicture and check this out. your answer is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_CAMERA,new CameraArguments());

to invoke the Camera

and FileSystemJournalListener to know which file is added in the file system